# CiviBoxOffice, subscriptions, seat maps, Fusiontickets

Tags: civievent

Years ago (2011-12) someone at the Bay Area Children's Theater worked on a seat map/subscription extension for CiviEvents. Is there anything new out there working today. (Fusiontickets seems to have disappeared and was required.)
We created a CiviCRM site for a community orchestra which offers a subscription series with assigned seating (and renewals available for the same "owned" seats like other season ticketholders might have.) Pricing is not dependent on seat type, but on age group of attendees (Senior/Adult/Student/Child) with single ticket sales at one rate (actually at 2: advanced sales and box office) and 4-concert and 3-concert subscription rates.

For all these assigned seating events, users select their seat from a map of the venue.

Has anyone done something similar within CiviCRM?